# ejabberd previous message received upon joining MUC room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Every time when a user joined a Multiple User Chat Room, the room will broadcast latest previous 20 messages to the user.

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

It happens that adding `history_size: 0` at `mod_muc` in the `ejabberd.yml` will turn off the message.